# My C code to compute smallest value of k for which sum is larger than user input n is not giving me the expected result?

Tags: c, loops, trace

I am practicing writing C codes for my upcoming test. The prompt is:

> 1. Write a program to compute the smallest value of k for which the following sum is larger than n. Get user input n and write a loop to compute the sum. Note that n can be a floating point number.
>
> (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/k) > n
>
> So n=2.0 should return k=4 since (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4)=2.08>2

I am not sure what I am doing wrong because when I run the program it doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int k=1;    
    double n, sum;  
    printf("Enter a value ");
    scanf("%lf", &n); //n=2     

    while(sum>=0 && sum<=n) //when n=2, 1=<1<2
    {
        sum= (1/k); 
        sum=sum++;  
        k++;        //when sum= 0    -> sum = 1 ,               k=1
                    //when sum= 1    -> sum = 1+ 1/2  = 1.5,    k=2
                    //when sum= 1.5  -> sum = 1.5 + 1/3 = 1.83, k=3
                    //when sum= 1.83 -> sum = 1.83 +1/4 = 2.8,  k=4
                    //sum is now 2.8 
                    //2.8>2 , k=4 so loop terminates    
    }

    printf("%d\n", k); //4  but it doesn't print anything???    
    return 0;           
}
```

I wrote my expected results on the comments besides my code.

Answer (score 2):

There were several problems with your code.

`sum= (1/k);` computes the *integer* division of 1 by k and it always give 0. Convert it to double to have a proper value

`sum=sum++;` Not sure what you wanted to do. `sum++` means `sum=sum+1` already.

And probably what you wanted to do is

`sum = sum + (1.0/k)`  1.0 ensures that result of division will be a double.

Initialisation was missing for sum.

Also, you counted one extra iteration. Better start at k=0 and increment at start of loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int k=0;    
    double n, sum=0.0;  
    printf("Enter a value ");
    scanf("%lf", &n); //n=2     

    while(sum>=0 && sum<=n) //when n=2, 1=<1<2
    {
        k++;        
        sum+=(1.0/k); 
                    //when sum= 0    -> sum = 1 ,               k=1
                    //when sum= 1    -> sum = 1+ 1/2  = 1.5,    k=2
                    //when sum= 1.5  -> sum = 1.5 + 1/3 = 1.83, k=3
                    //when sum= 1.83 -> sum = 1.83 +1/4 = 2.8,  k=4
                    //sum is now 2.8 
                    //2.8>2 , k=4 so loop terminates    
    }

    printf("%d\n", k); //4  but it doesn't print anything???    
    return 0;           
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out all my mistakes and even giving an explanation with it!! I initialized k as 1 cause I didn't want division by 0 and I never thought about incrementing k first. I made an equation for sum and then I wanted to update sum by adding the old sum after each iteration. I was being too extra and now I noticed that adding the 1 didn't make any sense. I was trying to increment sum by adding the old sum with the new sum. Idk why I did that because sum would get updated every time a new k is added. I forgot about initializing with decimals for double.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has many bugs:

- in the `while` condition, the program reads the value of `sum`, but that variable was never initialized before.

  This bug already means you didn't set the compiler warnings high enough. Modern compilers can fully analyze this situation and warn you.
- `sum = 1/k`

  This initializes the sum to 0.0 since k is of type `int`.
- `sum = sum++`

  Again undefined behavior since you are writing two values to the `sum` variable during a single statement.

As a general advice, there are programming languages other than C that would prevent all the above bugs by refusing to run this program. It may be a good idea to first write the program in such a safe language and, once finished, translate that program into C. (Java, Go, Kotlin are examples for safer programming languages.)

Comment: I haven't done java over a year. It will take me too long to figure everything out again.

Comment: It's your choice. You will shoot yourself into the foot numerous times if you continue programming like that in C. Just be warned.